# Jupyter -- opening notebooks on mac

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

This is a bit hard to explain so bear with me!  Suppose I have a Jupyter notebook in some directory. The only way I know to open it is to click repeatedly through the web based directory structure. Is there a nice way to do this using the mac finder.  In other words I would like a simple dialogue box to open from Jupyter to navigate to my notebook.

edit: thanks, I realized that I can start in certain directories, but what if I'm opening a bunch of different notebooks from different directories. It sure would be nice to be able to jump to my favorites easily.

Comment: you can start jupyter from a different directory with `jupyter notebook` in the terminal.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [Superuser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As @GiantsLoveDeathMetal mentions... if you navigate to a specific directory in your terminal and then type `jupyter notebook` the notebook will open and display in your browser, just the content of that folder.

**For example**:

```
$ cd /path/to/the/folder/with/your/notebook.ipynb

$ jupyter notebook
```

Comment: thanks, but I should have been more precise -- I've clarified my question above.